# AutoMapper - Map into destination object using property

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I have two objects

```
public class Dto 
{
   ICollection<DtoCollection> { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
   ICollection<ModelCollection> { get; set; }
}
```

And the following mapping configuration for them

```
public MappingProfile()
{
   CreateMap<Dto, Model>();
   CreateMap<DtoCollection, ModelCollection>()
}
```

With each `DtoCollection` and `ModelCollection` object having the same properties

```
public class DtoCollection
{
   public string InternalId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ModelCollection
{
   public string InternalId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have just created a `Dto` instance, and want to map that onto an existing `Model` instance. From my understanding, doing so will also map the nested *Collection* properties to each other.

However, I would like to only map items in the `DtoCollection` to the existing `ModelCollection` where each `InternalId` matches, instead of just adding new values to `ModelCollection`.

Is there a way to do this, in AutoMapper or by some other method?

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: try to read this article 
https://cpratt.co/using-automapper-mapping-instances/